# Python Read sheet of xls with accent in the name (xedses, xc3)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a xls with 'Países' as sheet_name and I can't open it. I try with:

```
import pandas
df3 = pandas.read_excel('a.xls', sheet_name='Pa\xedses', encoding='utf8')
df3 = pandas.read_excel('a.xls', sheet_name='Países', encoding='utf8')
```

Error:

```
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: No sheet named <'Pa\xedses'>
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: No sheet named <'Pa\xc3\xadses'>
```

SOLUTION:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a raw string worked for me:

```
df3 = pandas.read_excel('a.xls', sheet_name=r'Países')
```